# Getting a matching element from a different array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array called `groupUsers` and another array within an array called `tasks.users` which look like this:

```
this.groupUsers = [
{$id: "simpleLogin:1", name: "bob"},
{$id: "simpleLogin:2", name: "joe"}];

this.tasks = [
{title: "do something", users:["simpleLogin:1","simpleLogin:2"]},
{title: "do something else", users:["simpleLogin:2"]}];
```

What I am trying to do is to get the user's name from `groupUsers` to display when I show the tasks rather than their id, but I am unsure in how to go about getting it.  I assume it involves a filter?

With the following code I can display the tasks and the user id's assigned to each task, just not the names.

```
<div class="taskContainer"  ng-repeat="task in todo.tasks | orderBy:'-when'"> 
  <div><span ng-repeat="users in task.users">{{users}} </span></div> 
  <span> {{task.title}} </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand to this function to fit your needs, right now it will return one name of the passed in id, $filter is an angular-service, remember to include it in your controller

```
$scope.getName = function(id){
   return $filter('filter')(groupUsers, { name: id})[0].name;
 };
```

here is your html

```
<div class="taskContainer"  ng-repeat="task in todo.tasks | orderBy:'-when'"> 
  <div><span ng-repeat="users in task.users">{{getName(users[0])}} </span></div> 
  <span> {{task.title}} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't managed to get it working yet but I am pretty sure you have given me enough to get it working.